# How to use UIPickerView inside UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Hi I have a Table view Controller Name as `MyTableViewController`. In `MyTableViewController`, i am using different `UIPickerView` inside different `cell` of table which is name as `headerCell` which is set by the following function and in that i am not using any `UIPickerView`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "header") as! MyTableViewCell
    headerCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return headerCell
}
```

`MyTableViewCell` is class of `UITableViewCell` type in which, I have attached all table layouts like `Label`, `TextField`, `Button`,`UIPickerView` and etc.

My Second cell is `middleCell` an `footerCell` which is as

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : SubscriptionTableViewCell?
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "footer", for: indexPath) as? SubscriptionTableViewCell
        cell!.cardTypePicker.delegate = self
        cell!.expMonth.delegate = self
        cell!.expYear.delegate = self
        cell!.countryPicker.delegate = self
        cell!.shippingMethodPicker.delegate = self

        cell!.cardTypePicker.dataSource = self
        cell!.expMonth.dataSource = self
        cell!.expYear.dataSource = self
        cell!.countryPicker.dataSource = self
        cell!.shippingMethodPicker.dataSource = self

    }else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "middle", for: indexPath) as? SubscriptionTableViewCell
        cell!.variantPicker.delegate = self
        cell!.variantPicker.dataSource = self
    }
    return cell!
}
```

as you can see there are different `UIPickerView`.
So now i am not able to understand how should i use `UIPickerView` delegates inside `UITableViewController`.

Please help for that thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    
    var arrCountryName : [String] = []
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        arrCountryName = ["India" , "Australia"]
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}

extension TableViewCell : UIPickerViewDataSource , UIPickerViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return arrCountryName.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return arrCountryName[row]
    }   
}
```

Comment: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when try to add `Delegate`

Comment: @APKAPPS : have you try to add Delegate Methods in UITableViewCell ?

Comment: How we can add `UIPickerViewDelegate` to table cell while our `UIPickerView` is in `UITableViewController` so only we can add `Delegate` to our `UITableViewController` not to `UITableViewCell` if there is any way please tell me.

Comment: In your question you have mention that I have attach UIPickerView in UITableViewCell that is MyTableViewCell , so you have to add delegate method in UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

The term you are asking about is `Inline Picker`. There are so many ways to achieve this functionality. You can add a `UIPickerView` in your `UITableViewCell` and by making it's **height's constraint** you can modify it as you want. If you want to use third party picker you can refer below link:

https://github.com/sebamisc/UItableViewWithPicker

Answer (score 0):

There is a property on UIView called `tag` that you can use for any purpose you want.  You could assign the table's row number to it and then check for that in the delegate.

You need to be careful if you can insert or delete rows -- you need to reload affected rows and update the tag.

EDIT (another way):

You do not need to assign the same delegate to every picker.  You could make new classes that implement the delegate protocol.

So,

```
class CountryPickerDelegate: UIPickerDelegate {

// do what the country picker needs
// The init can take the VC if you need that.
// add a weak var viewController: MyTableViewController? = nil 

}

class CardTypePickerDelegate: UIPickerDelegate {

// do what the card picker needs
// The init can take the VC if you need that.
// add a weak var viewController: MyTableViewController = nil

}
```

Then,

```
cell!.countryPicker.delegate = CountryPickerDelegate(viewController: self)
```

Comment: Yes you are talking about tag.. `But how can i use tag for UIPickerview` or `UITableViewController`

Comment: I have use these class in both the way means as `inner class` and as `outer class` but it's not helping me out. can you please tell me the complete way to do that.

Comment: Post what you have and the problem you are having.

Comment: Can you please tell me the complete solution for `CountryPickerDelegate` class

Comment: While i am using your code first line `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments` where i am assigning `Delegate` & second is `Type 'CountryPickerDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'` this is class

Comment: Add `NSObject` to your inheritance list (so `class CardTypePickerDelegate: NSObject, UIPickerDelegate`)

Comment: You need to make an `init` that takes the ViewController as an argument and stores it in a property